# Не могу расшифровать AES

Tags: java, android, node.js, криптография, aes

Мой коллега шифрует данные с помощью AES-256 без вектора используя модуль node.js aes-js. Соотвественно ключ у него представляет из себя 32 размерный массив, а шифрованная строка - строка.

В Java Android я пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде того

```
 public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

Но мне всегда выдает ошибка -

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
```

А вот в TextView я загоняю таким способом

```
  byte[] key = new byte[]{83, 63, (byte) 180, (byte) 178, (byte) 169, 38, 21, 10, 62, (byte) 160, (byte) 216, (byte) 191, 122, 13, 55, 68, (byte) 181, 4, (byte) 180, 20, 8, 117, (byte) 138, 36, 51, 26, 7, 90, 3, (byte) 184, 47, 17};

    TextView t = findViewById(R.id.text);
    try {
        t.setText(Decrypt.decrypt(key, "cc1e55b3a5c6fbcc22c67bcafbb2e2704e25c9db8959f4a9d6570666d73fb15c49139b".getBytes()).toString());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Вот так шифрует и дешифрует коллега у себя

```
let encrypt = function(text, key){    
if(!key){
    key = KEY;
}
let encryptionBlock = new aes.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key, new aes.Counter(100));
return aes.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptionBlock.encrypt(aes.utils.utf8.toBytes(text)))
}
```

И дешифрование

```
let decrypt = function(text, key){    
if(!key){
    key = KEY;
}
let encryptionBlock = new aes.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key, new aes.Counter(100));
return aes.utils.utf8.fromBytes(encryptionBlock.decrypt(aes.utils.hex.toBytes(text)))
}
```

Как мне расшифровать этот текст? Уже множество способов перепробовал. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну все правильно, размер зашифрованных данных не кратен(!!!) размеру блока шифрования. Значит сразу делаем вывод об экзотическом режиме шифрования. Вы пытаетесь "в лоб" это расшифровать, на что вам говорят про ту саму не кратность. Нужны полные и подробные детали реализации шифрования у друга и расшифровки у вас. Тогда вы и сами поймете что делать.

Comment: Это похоже на `AES-CBC`. Под `SHA-256`, ибо `AES` - шифруется в `base64`, а у вас `SHA`.

Comment: Неплохо бы увидеть код шифрования

Comment: Добавил, как шифрует мой друг

Comment: @And А где вы там нашли SHA? И особенно интересно, где вы прочитали что AES шифруется в base64...

Comment: По коду шифрования - CTR режим, но даже в нем данные должны быть кратны размеру блока. Нужно больше деталей реализации.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы не правы, CTR работает по принципу потокового шифра, а значит длина шифротекста = длине плейнтекста.

Comment: @Zergatul какие ваши доказательства? Картинку со схемой работы CTR вы уже видели?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов мой код ниже в ответе расшифровывает 5 байт шифротекста в сообщение длиной 5 байт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум 2 вещи вы делаете неправильно:

1. `"...".getBytes()`. Зашифрованные данные - это бинарные данные, а не строка. Вы должны получить байты из hex строки, а не байты из символов.
2. Даже если вы первое сделаете верно, у вас длина зашифрованного сообщения - 35 байт. В AES она должна быть кратна размеру блока, то есть 16 байтам. Поэтому джава кидает исключение.

Я не знаю, каким образом было получено ваше зашифрованное сообщение, но оно точно не получено стандартным применением AES. Поэтому я не могу подсказать, как его расшифровать.

**После обновления вопроса.**

В случае с CTR нужно делать так:

```
byte[] ciphertext = new byte[] { 113, (byte)202, 74, (byte)141, 19 };
byte[] key = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
byte[] counter = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100 };
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
IvParameterSpec ctrParameter = new IvParameterSpec(counter);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ctrParameter);
byte[] plain = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
System.out.println(new String(plain, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Выводит `hello`. Обратите внимание на массив `counter`. Последний байт 100, что соответствует счетчику заданному в nodejs коде.

Еще могу добавить, что изпользование одного и того же счетчика с одним и тем же ключом очень большая дыра в безопасности, злоумышленник сможет расшифровать сообщение даже не зная ключа.

Comment: Показал, как он шифрует

Comment: @Ker_Jen я обновил ответ.

Comment: Как можно избежать такой дыры в безопасности?

Comment: Самый простой способ как решить проблему - генерировать каждый раз уникальный счетчик (желательно 16 уникальных байт, а не один байт, как сейчас), и пересылать его вместе с зашифрованным сообщением (например первые 16 байт - это счетчик). Злоумышленник будет видеть счетчик в таком случае, однако это ничего ему не даст.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    final byte[] bt = new byte[16];
    Arrays.fill(bt, (byte)0); 
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, bt);
    return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
}
```

Comment: Теперь мне выводит вот такую ошибку. java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: IV must be specified in CTR mode